# Firebase - Cannot convert call result type '[_]' to expected type '_?'

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I've been following the Firebase documentation and I've come up against this error and I'm unsure of how to get past it.

Here is my code and the error I get on line "let dataDescription = ..."

Cannot convert call result type '[*]' to expected type '*?'

```
let key = UserDefaults.standard.value(forKey: "uid") as! String
        let docRef = firebaseDB.collection("user").document(key)

        docRef.getDocument { (document, error) in
            if let document = document, document.exists {
                let dataDescription = document.data().map(String.init(describing:)) ?? "nil"
                print("Document data: \(dataDescription)")
            } else {
                print("Document does not exist")
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result of `document.data().map(String.init(describing:))` is a non optional array. The operator '??' expects an optional value. Just remove `?? "nil"` and it will work